# Stripe React Native: Native Code and Javascript Code out of sync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

With these versions of React Native and Stripe. Im getting the error in the image when calling `presentPaymentSheet`. Has someone already seen this error before?

```
"@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.26.0",
"react-native": "0.71.1",
```

---

```
export async function paymentProcess(info: PaymentInfoType) {
    const initResult = await initPaymentSheet({
        customerId: info.customerId,
        paymentIntentClientSecret: info.paymentIntentClientSecret,
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: info.ephemeralKeySecret,
        //
        ...initPaymentSheetParams,
    });

    if (initResult.error) {
        throw new Error('Failed on init.');
    }

    const result = await presentPaymentSheet({ timeout: 2000 });
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to delete both `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` file, and execute `yarn install` to build your react-native project from scratch.